# Give Excel style through SAS

Tags: excel, sas, export

I have the following issue.

I want to conver a sas7bdat data set into an excel file with some formatting and style.

The output of the sas data set is the following.
[image: Sas data set]

And the Excel output should be the following.
[image: Excel output]

How can I make the style change through SAS? I am very new to SAS and ODS or DDE, so can someone please give me a hand in this issue?

Very much appreciated in advance.

Thanks

Comment: If you're looking for how to do this generally, go use your search engine and look up the hundreds of papers on the topic.  We're happy to answer questions that arise from implementation, but this topic is too generic for this site.

Comment: What's surprising is the images in the question seem to have come straight out of Cynthia Zender's excellent paper on this topic.  http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/266-2011.pdf  That paper (and references) should have plenty of tips to get the OP started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I know of would be to create a template excel workbook with your desired style already applied, then use DDE to fill in the data ranges with the values from a matching SAS dataset. There are many resources that document how to do this.

Comment: DDE should be avoided if at all possible.  It's an old deprecated technology, it's not really supported, it is buggy, and has a lot of dependencies.  Having said that, there are some things that DDE can do that nothing else can, this is not one of them.